# Running a dhcp server on windows 7 ultimate

Tags: windows-7, dhcp-server

I'm trying to get my HP T5740 thin clients to connect to my local network without much success. I asked a question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/514712/how-to-connect-thin-clients-to-a-windows-network) but haven't got any response. I think that question should have been posted on serverfault instead.

I was thinking that the problem seems to be that the thin clients aren't able to get an IP address when they are connected and I can't manually set it. So if I was to somehow set up a `dhcp` server on the network with my server that runs a 32 bit version of windows 7 ultimate edition.

How do we set up a `dhcp` server in windows?

Comment: What's preventing you from setting the IP-address manually?

Comment: Windows 7 Embedded should allow you to set the address manually - can you set the static IP on the machine but it gets lost after reboot?

Comment: Also, Windows 7, as it is a desktop OS, does not have a DHCP server role. You'll need a Server OS for that, or consider using something like TFTP32 which can provide DNS, DHCP and TFTP services.

Comment: Please post some information about your clients and your network. There's no reason why you can't use static ip's with thin clients, and nor is running a dodgy dhcp server on your client OS the answer. Why can't these machines get a DHCP address from your infrastructure?

Comment: Install your favorite virtual machine software.  Create VM, bridge network, install Linux, setup dhcp server.  Done.  It would be far better to install Linux natively on a device though.

Comment: I have a server machine that runs windows 7 and a couple of D Link network switches. The fat clients have IPs assigned to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely can set a static IP on the HP T5740 - in fact, for the most part, they work just like full fat Windows. What problem are you having? I presume you've been logging in as admin and committing / disabling the write filter?

Comment: How do I log in as the administrator? It automatically starts up and then there is no option in the control panel for me to manage the network connection.

Comment: You need to log out and hold down `shift` to prevent it from logging in automatically. From there you can log in as the administrator - I recommend you take a read through the HP documentation first.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. Can I also Install other hardware drivers while running as the administrator?

Comment: @nikhil You certainly can